# Basic json_decode with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, json

I am trying to create a Wordpress plugin that will pull in a JSON file and(using a loop) create an element for each one of the objects in the JSON file. However, this particular JSON file is formatted in a way I have not seen and thus I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pull the data. The beginning and end of the file is marked with array brackets.

Here's the [JSON file](http://earthquake-report.com/feeds/recent-eq?json).

So the first object looks like this:

```
[{
    "title": "Moderate earthquake - Fiji Region on June 5, 2014",
    "magnitude": "4.5",
    "location": "FIJI REGION",
    "depth": "334",
    "latitude": "-15.63",
    "longitude": "-176.92",
    "date_time": "2014-06-05T04:17:31+00:00",
    "link": "http://earthquake-report.com/2014/06/05/moderate-earthquake-fiji-region-on-june-5-2014/"
},
```

So I've got this:

```
$json_feed_url = 'http://earthquake-report.com/feeds/recent-eq?json';
$args = array('timeout' => 120);
$json_feed = wp_remote_get($json_feed_url, $args);
$earthquake_data = json_decode($json_feed);
```

How do I actually pull this in and print it, though?  I can't just use $earthquake_data->title, and I need a way to be able to pull from each object using an index, as they don't have names.  Do I need to start at a 0 index and go from there?

```
echo $earthquake_data[0]; 
echo $earthquake_data[0]{$countervariable->title};
```

As I said, I want to pull the information from each of the last 25 objects in this document.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `foreach ($earthquake_data as $earthquake_data_single) { echo $earthquake_data_single->title; }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_feed_url = 'http://earthquake-report.com/feeds/recent-eq?json';
$args = array('timeout' => 120);
$json_feed = wp_remote_get($json_feed_url, $args);
$earthquake_data = json_decode($json_feed);

// $earthquake_data should be an array
foreach ($earthquake_data as $obj) {
  var_dump($obj);
  // example
  echo $obj->title;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... when I use the foreach function as you have written, I get this:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().  This is usually because it's not actually an array, right?
It appears it's actually not being created as an array.  
I created a little test function to find out:

if (!is_array($earthquake_data)) {
echo '<h1>ITS NOT AN ARRAY!</h1>';
 }

Needless to say, it printed out "It's not an array!".  Any ideas?

Comment: @thomasshellberg it would return false because `json_decode()` returns an `object`. If you want an `array` you'd use something like `json_decode($json_feed, true)` (note the second parameter `true`)

Comment: @Darren False. JSON arrays are still arrays (0, 1, 2, 3.. keys). Named keys, however, will be object properties.

Comment: @thomasshellberg Try out `var_dump($earthquake_data)` and post a minimal result in the OP. It might be `FALSE` if the data wasn't parsed correctly.

Comment: @h2ooooooo touche, thanks for pointing out my stupidity. It's been a long day :(

Comment: @Darren No problem - my day just started, and I still need my morning coffee. I know how you feel :)

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the file as i don't use wp.

The trick is to use 'json_decode(*data*, **true**) as then PHP converts all objects to arrays. Just a couple of 'foreach' loops will print it, select from it etc.

here is some tested sample code.

```
<?php
$dc = json_decode(file_get_contents('earthquake.json'), true);

foreach ($dc as $details) {
    echo '<strong>', $details['title'], '</strong><br />';
    foreach($details as $name => $value) {
        echo $name, ' => ', $value, '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This worked after downloading the file as a .json and using it locally.  I also just changed 'earthquake.json' to the feed URL and it worked as well.  If I used the wp_remote_get function the way I previously did, it didn't work.  I'm guessing that was the problem the whole time.  Thanks again!